# Value Error Missing when using POST with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm building a simple API with FastAPI using the official documentation, but when I try to test it with postman I get the same error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError
```

Here is my model:

```
class Owner(BaseModel):
  name: str
  address: str
  status: int
```

My endpoint:

```
@app.post('/api/v1/owner/add', response_model=Owner)
async def post_owner(owner: Owner):
   return conn.insert_record(settings.DB_TABLE_OWN, owner)
```

And my method to insert it to the database (RethinkDB)

```
@staticmethod
def insert_record(table, record):
    try:
        return DBConnection.DB.table(table).insert(record.json()).run()
    except RqlError:
        return {'Error': 'Could not insert record'}
```

This is the JSON I send using postman:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "address": "Test address",
  "status": 0
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for Owner
response -> name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> address
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> status
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I gotta say that it was running fine until I stopped the server and got it running again.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 7):

You have set the ***`response_model=Owner`*** which results in FastAPI to validate the response from the **`post_owner(...)`** route. Most likely, the
**`conn.insert_record(...)`** is not returning a response as the ***Owner*** model.

#### Solutions

1. Change `response_model` to an appropriate one
2. Remove `response_model`

Answer (score 1):

Import `List` from `typing` module:

```py
from typing import List
```

then change `response_model=Owner` to `response_model=List[Owner]`

Answer (score 0):

@app.post('/api/v1/owner/add', response_model=Owner)
def post_owner(owner: Owner):
conn.insert_record(settings.DB_TABLE_OWN, owner)
return owner

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).